# MIPS - More than 4 strings as parameters

Tags: string, mips

I am trying to implement `puts` in MIPS. I made it work with `$a0`. It printed the string starting at the address of that register. However, I am now trying to implement `puts` for an arbitrary amount of strings, meaning that I can't use the registers anymore. I am confused as to how to use the stack efficiently. From my main procedure, I stack an arbitrary amount of strings. I then want to `jal` to `puts`, which will print all the strings. I also pass on top of the stack the number of strings to print.

Here is my code for `puts` :

```
# puts - prints ASCII to the screen
#    prints from $a0, $a1, $a2, $a3 (buffers)
#    stops when chracter is NULL
#   ASSUME THAT WHEN PUTS IS CALLED, AT LEAST ONE STRING IS PASSED
#
# CALLING CONVENTION
#
# I decided not to use any of the registers $a0-$a4. 
# Instead, the caller stacks all the strings it wants to print in the stack. 
# On top of it, it adds the number of strings it wants to print.
# puts will loop, printing each string, until it has printed all of them.
#
# Since the caller is using "s" registers, puts must save them to the stack. 
# Thus, these will be put on top of the stack.
# puts will have to access the strings below the stacked registers.
#
#   ============  STACK DIAGRAM ==============
#
#   \   Number of Strings   \ TOP
#   \       String 1        \ +200      
#   \       String 2        \ +400
#   \       String 3        \ +600
#   \       String 4        \ +800
#   \       String 5        \ +/000
#   \       String 6        \ +...
#   \         ...       \ 
#
# on entry:
#   $ra -- return address
#   0($sp) -- number of strings to print
#   x($sp) -- strings to print
#
# on exit:
#   $v0 -- number of character printed
#       
    .text
puts:
    addi $sp, $sp, -20  # make room for 6 registers
    sw $ra, 16($sp)     # save $ra on the stack
    sw $s0, 12($sp)     # save $s0 on the stack
    sw, $s1, 8($sp)     # save $s1 on the stack
    sw, $s2, 4($sp)     # save $s2 on the stack
    sw, $s3, 0($sp)     # save $s3 on the stack

    lw $s0, 224($sp)    # copy address of first string inside $s0
    lw $s1, 24($sp)     # copy number of strings to print inside $s1
    move $s2, $zero     # counter for the number of strings printed
    move $s3, $zero     # counter for the number of characters sent to putchar

putsString:
**  lbu $t3, ($s0)      # load ccurrent char into #t3
    beq $t3, $zero, exitString  # exit puts if the current character is the NULL character

    move $a0, $t3       # put the character to print inside $a0, accessible by putchar
    jal putchar     # print char using putchar
    addi $s3, $s3, 1    # character count += 1
    addi $s0, $s0, 4    # increment string address by 1 word (4 bytes)
    j putsString        # Loop to print next character
exitString:
    addi $s2, $s2, 1    # increment number of strings printed
    beq $s1, $s2, exitPuts  # if # of strings to print = # of strings printed, then exit puts; else, increment # of strings printed
    addi $s0, $s0, 200  # $s0 now points to next string to print
    j putsString
exitPuts:   
    move $v0, $s4       # return number of character printed
    lw $s3, 0($sp)      # restore stack
    lw $s2, 4($sp)      # -
    lw $s1, 8($sp)      # -
    lw $s0, 12($sp)     # -
    lw $ra, 16($sp)     # -
    addi $sp, $sp, 20   # pop from stack
    jr $ra          # return
```

The line with a ** is the faulty one for now. I get `Runtime exception at 0x00400124: address out of range 0x00000000`.

Here is how I save the strings to the stack (I read 2 (2 is hardcoded) strings for now with `gets`).

```
init:
    beq $s0,2,continue
    move $a0, $s2       # load buffer address into $a0          
    la $t1, limit       # - load limit into $a1             
    lb $a1, ($t1)       # - ...
    jal gets        # call gets - it will modify buffer     
    move $t0, $v0       # $t0 = string count returned by gets
moveBufferToStack:
    lbu $t1, ($s2)      # get first character inside buffer
    beqz $t1, endMoveBuffer
    sw $t1, ($sp)       # copy buffer(i) into array(i)

    addi $sp, $sp, 4    # array pointer points a position forward
    addi $s2, $s2, 4    # same for array pointer
    j moveBufferToStack
endMoveBuffer:
    addi $sp, $sp, 200  # step to next array cell 
    addi $s0, $s0, 1    # increment number of strings read
    j init          # loop until we have 9 elements
continue:           
    jal puts
    j done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just focusing on the problem line, I see this:

```
lw $s0, 224($sp)    # copy address of first string inside $s0
...
putsString:
lbu $t3, ($s0)      # load ccurrent char into #t3
```

So you've loaded `$s0` with the *contents* of the memory starting 224 bytes past `$sp`. If I'm understanding correctly, that's the first four bytes of a string. Meaning, if the string is "Madam, I'm Adam", that `$s0` contains 'a' 'd' 'a' 'M' (if I've got my endianness right).

So when you do `lbu $t3, ($s0)`, you're not loading the current *character* into `$t3`. You're loading the byte *pointed to by* `$s0`, which is going to be a random spot in memory. If your string is blank, `$s0` might contain 0x00000000 - and thus would generate the error you're getting.

I think what you want to do, instead of `lw`, is `addi $s0, $sp, 224`. Then, $s0 will point to the address at $sp + 224.

Comment: You are right! I was definitely not addressing properly. I implemented your solution, but go a curious error `DEVELOPER: You must use getStatement() to read from kernel text segment!` (I guess I was accessing memory outside of the one allocated for my program). It turns out that `puts` is very easy to implement without the stack! I simply store the strings in an array of strings. Then I pass the address of the first string in $a0 and the number of strings in $a1. I was overcomplicating things!

Comment: Oh, right... I forgot that the stack grows *down*, not *up*. If I'm remembering right, `$sp` starts at the top of memory. If you add to it, you'll end up in someone else's playground (ie, the kernel text segment). The references to `$sp` should have involved subtraction, not addition.